# Flask-Talisman. whitelisting sha256 not working

Tags: flask, content-security-policy

I have this config for flask-talisman

```
'style-src-elem':[
    'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com',
    '\'self\'',
    'https://fonts.googleapis.com',
    'https://www.paypal.com',
    'sha256-Y5HGV3cmFL1QmdV9FMkQjm7MR7FR+stNxbf9+GKET60=',
    'sha256-47DEQpj8HBSa+/TImW+5JCeuQeRkm5NMpJWZG3hSuFU=',
    'sha256-oRjZhdNA+hM09jMYLHOUU2VtMxrmznym5tWJmiyI+Oo=',
    'sha256-IVUmBkRCdvydC0Uh8tn6KMTNiZNvKrJOMResPyDMax8=',
    'sha256-rdzt5ui2VGkyv3dNYnGUDmT5J+N5RyuwQE1Rbx/kcFM=',
    'sha256-47DEQpj8HBSa+/TImW+5JCeuQeRkm5NMpJWZG3hSuFU='
],
```

the browser returns an error that

`The source list for Content Security Policy directive 'style-src-elem' contains an invalid source: 'sha256-47DEQpj8HBSa+/TImW+5JCeuQeRkm5NMpJWZG3hSuFU='. It will be ignored.`

how do I add the hash to my list?

here is the CSP returned by Flask

```
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self' https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com https://www.sandbox.paypal.com https://www.paypal.com; style-src-elem https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com 'self' https://fonts.googleapis.com https://www.paypal.com sha256-Y5HGV3cmFL1QmdV9FMkQjm7MR7FR+stNxbf9+GKET60= sha256-47DEQpj8HBSa+/TImW+5JCeuQeRkm5NMpJWZG3hSuFU= sha256-oRjZhdNA+hM09jMYLHOUU2VtMxrmznym5tWJmiyI+Oo= sha256-IVUmBkRCdvydC0Uh8tn6KMTNiZNvKrJOMResPyDMax8= sha256-rdzt5ui2VGkyv3dNYnGUDmT5J+N5RyuwQE1Rbx/kcFM= sha256-47DEQpj8HBSa+/TImW+5JCeuQeRkm5NMpJWZG3hSuFU=; style-src https://www.paypal.com; img-src *; script-src 'self' https://www.paypal.com https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com 'nonce-DuvsKN_8mn0-PxpaMd7CEA'; font-src https://fonts.gstatic.com; connect-src *
```

Comment: Please post the value of the actual Content-Security-Policy HTTP response header that the flask server is sending out on the wire in its response.

Comment: OK, so the problem’s that the `sha256-` hashes in the Content-Security-Policy are unquoted. So I guess the fix is that in the flask-talisman config, you need to put escaped quotes around all of them — e.g., `'\'sha256-Y5HGV3cmFL1QmdV9FMkQjm7MR7FR+stNxbf9+GKET60=\'' — just as you already have for `'\'self\''`. That way, they’ll end up quoted in the actual Content-Security-Policy response header value that flask sends out on the wire.

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH! now I have to handle the paypal CSP problem this time.